# Using Amazon S3 SDK in the browser for multipart upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It seems like the way to go is a class [Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html#upload) in package `@aws-sdk/lib-storage`. It's a class that [used to be called ManagedUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712695/s3-managedupload-equivalent-in-aws-javascript-sdk-v3?rq=1) and which supports multipart uploads. However when trying to import `@aws-sdk/lib-storage`, I get the error below, so apparently the package only works on Node, not the browser.
[image]

For the browser, what is the best alternative for someone who wants to implement multipart uploads to S3?

Comment: See [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html#welcome_web) for using the v3 JavaScript SDK in the browser. Alternatively, you could use v2 but I'd go with v3 if you can.

Comment: @jarmod I'm using next.js/webpack. Someone just pointed out this issue to me: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2564 - it sounds like there's no easy workaround, so yeah, probably will try v2.