# @aws-sdk/client-s3, Why I got an unhandled error event when a step in pipeline throws an error?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-s3-client

I have a case when a transform stream throws an error in pipeline while the stream is handled by the method **send** of s3 client instance.

The error thrown is not caught by the try catch in the code.

I isolated the problem in a small example here: https://github.com/HalexV/throw-error-s3-upload.

The project uses a node version 18.

To run the example:

```
cd into the folder
nvm use
npm ci
docker compose up -d
npm start
```

I'm using async generators to create the readable and transform (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streams-compatibility-with-async-generators-and-async-iterators).

If I change the uploadS3 to an async generator writable, the error is caught by the try catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my question wasn't answered, I tried to debug my code and I found something interesting.

At a certain moment I stopped at this code below on debugging:
[image]

Marked in red is the condition where the code was executed. This part of the code says that we are using a stream without a known length and recommends to use method Upload of the @aws-sdk/lib-storage.

I found a [stackoverflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70159394/16505174) that helped me to use the method Upload instead of using the method send with PutObjectCommand. The previous way, the error wasn't caught correctly.

So, consulting the [@aws-sdk/lib-storage](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/lib/lib-storage), I fix the code and the error was caught correctly.
[image]
[image]